# Required choice field having 0 rows in OBIEE

Tags: filter, prompt, obiee, choicefield

We have a required prompt with a choice list. If that choice list in empty, as the default selection of 'all column values', OBIEE is fetching everything. Is it possible to return nothing when the choice list is empty?

Comment: Really need some help guys.
I have tried everything I know, searched a lot too and I am still new to OBIEE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dummy value inside the default selection? in that way the dummy value will not match for the filter condition and will not retrieve any data. 
Of course, the dummy value has to be base on case statement.

Comment: I did that as well. In the backend query, this dummy value got ignored. More like the entire column wasn't present in the where clause, Nik_b.